# NEXT, upload file along with metadata (Axios and Formidable with Node JS)

Tags: rest, next.js, formidable

I want to upload a file to NEXT apis along with metadata:

```
const data = new FormData();
      data.append('file', file);
      data.append('body', JSON.stringify({ hello: 'world' }));
      console.log('Sending');
      axios
        .post('/api/test-route', data, {
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': 'json-token',
          },
        })
        .then((response: AxiosResponse) =>
          console.log('data = ', response.data)
        )
        .catch((error: unknown) => console.log(error));
```

Here's my API Code:

```
// Backend
import formidable from 'formidable';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import {
  errorResponse,
  genericResponse,
  getErrorDetailsFromKey,
} from '@global-backend/utils/api/responseSynthesizer';
import {
  ErrorCodes,
  IResponse,
} from '@constants/interfaces/gcorn/backend/apis/response.interfaces';

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  //@ts-ignore
  form.uploadDir = './'; //@ts-ignore
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  const opsDetails = getErrorDetailsFromKey(
    ErrorCodes.INVALID_OR_CORRUPTED_FILE
  );
  let response = errorResponse({ opsDetails });
  let status_code = 400;
  const payload: { response: IResponse; status_code: number; error: boolean } =
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      let flag = 0;
      form.parse(req, (err, _, files) => {
        const isError = err?.message !== undefined;
        if (isError) {
          response = errorResponse({
            message: err.message,
            opsDetails,
          });
          status_code = 400;
        }
        console.log('Files = ', Object.keys(files.file));
        const fileCheck = checkImageFileValidity(files.file as unknown as File);
        if (fileCheck.error) {
          opsDetails.details = fileCheck.message;
          response = errorResponse({
            message: fileCheck.message,
            opsDetails,
          });
          status_code = 400;
        }
        response = genericResponse({
          status_code: 201,
          opsDetails: getErrorDetailsFromKey(
            ErrorCodes.FUNFUSE_PROFILE_UPDATE_SUCESS
          ),
        });
        status_code = 201;
        flag = 1;
        resolve({ response, status_code, error: false });
      });
    });
  return res.status(payload.status_code).json(payload.response);
};

const checkImageFileValidity = (
  file: File
): { error: boolean; message: string } => {
  const { type, size } = file;
  // Must be less than 5MBs in Size and Must be Image File
  if (size > 5000000)
    return { error: true, message: 'File Size More than 5MBs' };
  if (!type.includes('image'))
    return { error: true, message: 'File is not an image' };
  return { error: false, message: 'File is valid' };
};
```

But for some reason, I don't know how can I parse `body` part of my form which extracts the info: `{hello:world}`.

Does anyone know a way to parse it and collect in the backend ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else is correct, you need to check the _ variable